# jquery post more than once (chat)

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get, chat

I'm trying to make a ajax chat.
The code works fine, if i only send 1 text, but if i send a second text, it doesn't work:

```
$("#nachricht_absenden").click(function () {
        $.post("functions/chatnachricht.php", $("#messages_schreiben").serialize(), function( data ) {
          $("#messages_nachricht").html( data );
    });
```

If i click on the "nachricht_absenden" button once, the nachricht is sent, but if i click on the button again, it won't send again.

Sorry for my bad english. Please help. Thanks ;)

Comment: is #nachricht_absenden inside of #messages_nachricht?

Comment: Probably because you're overwriting the original HTML with the new HTML, losing the event-handlers.

Comment: If the problem is what @DavidThomas said, you should declare that ajax as `$(document).on('click', '#nachricht_absenden', function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

If `#nachricth_absenden` is inside `#messages_nachricht` it won't work because you are overriding the origin HTML, therefore `#nachricth_absenden` may not existe in the second call. If it still exists, the new element doesn't have the `click` event asigned so you will have to asign the `click` event again to your new element `#nachricth_absenden`.

Not because it has the same id means it is the same element. You may be overriding it but you think it is the same because you have a new `#nachricth_absenden` element. But this one does not have the events binded.